# ischecked function

Tags: qt

I used the "ischecked" function for a checkbox, it works fine for it. I used the same function for pushbutton. The default state is "unchecked" for a pushbutton, so it is working fine in that case, but when I go to the properties of pushbutton and change the state to checked and try to work on it like

```
if(ui->Button->isChecked()==Qt::Checked)
{
ui->label_2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
ui->frame_10->setMinimumHeight(image.size().height() + 20);
}
```

then I can see no changes in the dialogbox. Why is this happening? What should I do inorder to make it work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the "checkable" property of your button to true after it has been created:

```
Button->setCheckable(true);
```

At [QAbstractButton::checkable()](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qabstractbutton.html#checkable-prop):

> This property holds whether the button is checkable. **By default, the
>   button is not checkable.**